# laravel assertJsonValidationErrors() does not exist

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

when I use  assertJsonValidationErrors() testing method in laravel 5.5 I get the following error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::assertJsonValidationErrors()
```

I don't know what is wrong.other testing methods work fine for me.
this is my test method :

```
public function test_user_login_when_phone_is_empty()
{
    $response = $this->json(
        'POST',
        route('login'),
        [
            'phone' => '',
            'password' => 'sdfksfhas4u'
        ]
    );

    $response
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors(['phone'])
        ;
}
```

any help guys?

Comment: Can you post your error stacktrace and give us the link?

Comment: if you mean stack trace in log file, there is nothing related to this error in my log file @NikolaGavric

Comment: Just tried that method on a fresh laravel 5.5 application and here is what I get https://imgur.com/a/UAaQz

Comment: according to laravel's documentation everything should be OK but it's not!
I'm confused.any suggestion? @NikolaGavric

Comment: I honestly don't know, I can't even seem to find that function in `Laravel` files..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests#assert-json-validation-errors @NikolaGavric

Comment: I know it's in their documentation, but here is what I get when I search for that method in their framework https://imgur.com/a/TP44U

Answer (score 0):

**assertJsonValidationErrors** is a method of **Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse**, not **Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse**

My guess is that you might have forgotten to extend TestCase.

Comment: No , I have extended TestCase in my test class